# Angular 7 Unable to remove child cookie path

Tags: angular, ngx-cookie-service

I am working on angular 7, And using ngx-cookie-service
I had create two different path.

```
this.cookieService.delete('_logdetails', "/admin", "abc.com");
this.cookieService.delete('_logdetails_home');
```

Root path cookie is remove but child cookies is not remove.

It's working on localhost but while production it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me...

I have changed the name while set the cookie data.

then I have changed `this.cookieService.delete('test');`

or You can use `this.cookieService.deleteAll();`